# Assuming x real, simplifying or refining Im[1/(x+i)] doesn't yield anything

Tags: complex, algebraic-manipulation, assumptions, algebra

I think it is straightforward from the title,

```
Simplify[Im[1/(x+I)], x > 0]
```

spits out,

```
Im[1/(x+I)]
```

while I would have liked,

```
- 1/(x^2+1)
```

Isn't there any easy way to get this result? I think there should be something simpler than dividing by the complex conjugate of the denominator, simplifying, then multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator and finally simplifying again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ComplexExpand` to simplify, assuming variables are real

```
ComplexExpand[Im[1/(x + I)]]
(* -(1/(1 + x^2)) *)
```

Comment: Nice, that seems to work well, but that's a shame `Simplify` or `Refine` don't do it.

Comment: @OlivierMassicot - Evaluate `Greater @@ (LeafCount /@ {ComplexExpand[Im[1/(x + I)]], 
    Simplify[Im[1/(x + I)], x > 0]})` and you will see why. `ComplexExpand` gives you easier control over the form of complex expressions, particularly if you use the option `TargetFunctions`.